# (そして彼女は窓際の壁を背に床に座り込む) - What does 壁を背に床に座り込む mean?

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-に, particle-を, object

> そして彼女は**窓際の壁を背に床に座り込む。** - And then she sat against the wall to the side of the window.

Judging the meaning, I think I managed to grasp what it means but I'm confused about how this sentence works.

I thought of this literal translation of what I think of this sentence

> And then to her back she sits into the floor

1. I think that the に in 背に an indirect object marker
2. I think that the 2nd　に is the location marker
3. I can't really think of how 壁を座り込む works...